# Is it possible to detect SQlite 3 compilation options from C API?

Tags: sqlite

Does SQLite 3 provide macros or some other way to check compilation options from the preprocessor? Basically, I want to write a function which calls `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` if SQLite was compiled without `SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` and returns a error code otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a function over here:
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/compileoption_get.html

Comment: In that case you can explicitly check for the existence of the symbol using `dlsym` and throw an error in the user's face if it's not available.